# promise - react - props - Unable to send promise as route props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-router, react-redux

In the below code if the first call fails and the second call returns response, the cp value updated inside catch block is not available as props. The cp has the error which was the response of first call. I need the response of second call to be available in my component

```
cp = getcp() // getcp returns promises
  cp.catch(ex => {
   if (ex) {
   cp = getcp()
   cp.catch(ex => {
    cp = {}
   })
  } else {
    cp = {}
  }
})
```

I am sending the cp value in route as `<Route path={ PAGE } component={ component } onEnter={ refresh } cp={ cp }/>` and in component I am taking it has this.props.route.cp

If the first call is success the cp is properly passed. this.props.route.cp in the chid component returns the cp value. This actually fails only on second call

Answer (score 0):

I guess custom props is no longer work in react-router v4. You might want to prepare a function that returns your component like below.

```
const PassComponent = (props) => {
    return (
    <ProductPage 
        cp={this.cp.bind(this)}
    />
    );
}
```

And call it this way

```
Route path={ PAGE } component={ PassComponent } onEnter={ refresh } />
```

Reference : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105

Comment: #Hana Alaydrus If the first call is success the cp is properly passed. this.props.route.cp in the chid component returns the cp value. This actually fails only on second call

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't pass promises to child components as React is designed to work best when properties are immutable. In any event, when you change the value of `cp`, it is not triggering a render and hence your child component is not updating.

Instead, run the promise and handle the result by calling `setState` in the parent to modify the component state. This will trigger a re-render  and you can pass the child component the correct value from `this.state`.

Comment: @Matin Campbell If the first call is success the cp is properly passed. this.props.route.cp in the chid component returns the cp value. This actually fails only on second call

Comment: If you posted a more complete code sample then I'd be able to help further. However, you set `cp = getcp()` inside the catch method for when the first call fails. How does this updated value of `cp` get to the child component? Objects are pass by reference in Javascript and the child component will still be referring to the old value unless you are triggering another render somehow.

Comment: The getcp call is made in routex.jsx(in the first view) and when I try to access the this.props.route.cp in cp view, the first call response is send